# How to change input option text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to target this input and change it dynamically with jQuery:

```
<select id="sub_cat" style="" name="sub_cat">
<option selected="selected" value="-10">All</option>
```

I want to be able to change 'All' with an if statement based on different variables. Is this possible with jQuery? And how? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `$('#option_id').text('target text');` would change the option text to whatever you want, the if statements shouldn't be too hard to do

Comment: @Izzey got it, why didnt u just post it as an answer?

Comment: @NicolasBrown I'm too lazy :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HRxRM/)

```
var option = $('#sub_cat').find('option:contains("All")');
option.text('New Text');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will change the value of the selected option depending on the value of a `lang` variable.

```
$("#sub_cat option").each(function() {
  var option = $(this);
  var val = option.val();
  if(val === "All") option.val("Hepsi");
});
```